# Moving Tridion 9.5 databases to PaaS

Tags: sites-9.5, azure

We are planning to move from IaaS setup of our Tridion CM and CD databases from Azure to PaaS setup in Azure.
Wanted to know if anyone here has done this before on azure sql server with server less and elastic pool ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you mean exactly with "PaaS setup in Azure"? It is more than using SQL Azure?